# How do I conditionally display a Javascript alert() that blocks the page from submitting until the user clicks "OK"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a commandButton like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.checkDetails}" action="#{bean.save}" />
```

My checkDetails() method checks some fields on the page and if they are not filled in, uses RequestContext to trigger a Javascript alert() which I want to use to block bean.save from being called until the user clicks "OK".  The RequestContext piece looks like this:

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.execute("alert('Details are not Complete.')");
```

My problem is I am not seeing the alert() dialog and bean.save is being called regardless of the state of the checkDetails() method.

Am I going about this completely the wrong way?  I have spent three hours on this so far and I am plain stuck.  If I remove the action method, the alert() pops up just fine.

Please, any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably need to prevent default or return false before the submit

Comment: What clumsy and oldschool. Why don't you make use of JSF (or even PrimeFaces) builtin validation and messaging facilties? In case of a validation fail, the action method won't even be hit at all, nor would the model values be updated. The simplest validation wich JSF offers is just putting `required="true"` in the appropriate input components. With the PrimeFaces `<p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>` you will get instant validation messages by ajax. See also this showcase example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf

Comment: Thanks BalusC but I am recreating an application in a like-for-like fashion.  I am in fact using `required="true"` for many fields already.  I just need to display this Javascript alert() and I only want to block the action method from executing, not stop it completely.  As soon as the user presses OK on the alert(), the action method should execute.

Answer (score 0):

> My checkDetails() method checks some fields on the page and if they are not filled in...

As BalusC said, this can very easily be solved by adding `required="true"` to those fields, no need to write Java for this.

If you want to mix this up with the 'old-scool' `alert()` you can use the `validationFailed` callback parameter:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText required="true" />
    <p:commandButton value="submit" oncomplete="handleValidation(xhr, status, args)" />
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleValidation(xhr, status, args)
    {
        if(args.validationFailed)
        {
            alert('Details are not Complete.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I need more to be able to do more with the values on the page than just a simple `required="true"`.  I want to run a method in the backing bean that has the ability to popup JS alert()'s and then when the method is finished I want the action method to execute.

Comment: @peetss Maybe you should specify what you want to do with the fields. ;-)